# Limit the data points in Highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have a following statement and it generates the mentioned output by averaging data within every 20 minutes of range.

**Statement :**

```
SELECT record_no, date_time, 
ROUND(AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_time))) AS time_value, 
ROUND(AVG(ph1_active_power),4) AS p1, 
ROUND(AVG(ph2_active_power),4) AS p2, 
ROUND(AVG(ph3_active_power),4) AS p3 
FROM powerpro1
GROUP BY date_time DIV 2000
```

**Portion of the output**

```
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
| record_no |      date_time      | time_value |   p1    |    p2    |    p3    |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
|         1 | 2014-12-01 00:00:00 | 1417372770 | 72.6242 | -68.7428 | -72.6242 |
|        21 | 2014-12-01 00:20:00 | 1417373970 | 71.6624 | -69.7448 | -71.6624 |
|        41 | 2014-12-01 00:40:00 | 1417375170 | 70.6869 | -70.7333 | -70.6869 |
|        61 | 2014-12-01 01:00:00 | 1417376370 | 69.6977 | -71.7082 | -69.6977 |
|        81 | 2014-12-01 01:20:00 | 1417377570 | 68.6952 | -72.6692 | -68.6952 |
|       101 | 2014-12-01 01:40:00 | 1417378770 | 67.6794 | -73.6162 | -67.6794 |
|       121 | 2014-12-01 02:00:00 | 1417379970 | 66.6505 | -74.549  | -66.6505 |
|       141 | 2014-12-01 02:20:00 | 1417381200 | 65.5825 | -75.4901 | -65.5825 |
+-----------+---------------------+------------+---------+----------+----------+
```

According to the no of records in the table named "powerpro1", the above query selects 1368 records when the executing. (May be increased in the future when receiving new records)

My requirement is to create a highchart using time_value for the x-axis and p1, p1 and p3 for the y-axis. **But I needs to limit the no of points in the x-axis**.

Can anyone like to help me to show this 1368 points by 1000 points in the chart

Comment: Why you cannot set LIMIT=1000 in the SQL query?

Comment: do you mean you only want to show 1,000 of the points you return, or that you want to change the way you average the points so that it returns 1,000 records, while still covering the full time span? Two very different questions

Comment: No. I want to show the returned any no of records (like 900, 1200) by 1000 points

Comment: So if you have i.e 700 points, 1000 should be displayed?

Comment: @Sebastian. Yes. if I have i.e 700 points, 1000 should be displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately have no this kind of apporixmation, only in reverse order (I mean datagrouping, if you have 100 points, return i.e 10). So you need to calcualte it on your own and push to your data all 1000 points.